# Farbtastic Multiple Fields - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress theme. I am working on the theme options page right now. I added farbtastic (4 fields) and the problem is that every time I click on the input, the color picker appears on the other 3 fields too. Anybody knows how to fix this? Thank you!

```
<div> <br />
  <label for="<?php echo $colorPicker['ID']; ?>"><?php _e($colorPicker['label']); ?></label>
  <input type="text" class="color-picker" id="<?php echo $colorPicker['ID']; ?>" value="<?php echo get_option($colorPicker['ID']); ?>" name="<?php echo $colorPicker['ID']; ?>" />
  <div id="<?php echo $colorPicker['ID']; ?>_color" class="fabox"></div>            </div>          
<?php endforeach; ?>            
<p><input type="submit" name="update_options" value="Update Options" class="button-primary" /></p>
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var colorPickers = $('.color-picker');
    console.log(colorPickers);
    for (e in colorPickers) {
        if (colorPickers[e].id != undefined) {
            var colorPickerID = colorPickers[e].id;
            $('#' + colorPickerID + '_color').farbtastic('#' + colorPickerID);
        }
    }

    $('.fabox').hide();


    $('.color-picker').click(function() {
        $('.fabox').fadeIn();
    });

    $(document).mousedown(function() {
        $('.fabox').each(function() {
            var display = $(this).css('display');
            if (display == 'block') $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    });
});​
</script>
```

HTML OUTPUT:

```
<form method="POST" action="">  

                        <div>

            <br />

            <label for="color_1"><strong>Post Title</strong></label>

            <input type="text" class="color-picker" id="color_1" value="#273990" name="color_1" />

            <div id="color_1_color" class="fabox"></div>

            </div>

                        <div>

            <br />

            <label for="color_2"><strong>Paragraph Text</strong></label>

            <input type="text" class="color-picker" id="color_2" value="#840000" name="color_2" />

            <div id="color_2_color" class="fabox"></div>

            </div>

                        <div>

            <br />

            <label for="color_3"><strong>Example</strong></label>

            <input type="text" class="color-picker" id="color_3" value="#4377df" name="color_3" />

            <div id="color_3_color" class="fabox"></div>

            </div>

                        <div>

            <br />

            <label for="color_4"><strong>And Another Example</strong></label>

            <input type="text" class="color-picker" id="color_4" value="#3c8400" name="color_4" />

            <div id="color_4_color" class="fabox"></div>

            </div>

                        <p><input type="submit" name="update_options" value="Update Options" class="button-primary" /></p>

        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: I think you're referencing too broad of an element with your jQuery selector. Essentially your code says every time you click anything with the `color-picker` class, show anything with the `fabox` class. You should make your reference more specific to the currently clicked `.color-picker`. Maybe replace `$('.fabox').fadeIn();` with `$(this).parent().find('.fabox').fadeIn();`, or something similar to that.

Comment: ericissocial thanks a lot for your help. Your code you provided did the magic! Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referencing too broad of an element with your jQuery selector. Essentially your code says every time you click anything with the `color-picker` class, show anything with the `fabox` class.

You should make your reference more specific to the currently clicked `.color-picker`.

I recommend replacing this:

```
$('.fabox').fadeIn();
```

With this:

```
$(this).parent().find('.fabox').fadeIn();
```

So you are only referencing the `.fabox` that is connected to the `.color-picker` you just clicked.

**EDIT**: As gillesc noted, it would actually be quicker to use:

```
$(this).next().fadeIn();
```

So long as the the `.fabox` always follows the `.color-picker`.

If the `.fabox` was inside the same container, but not the very next element you could use:

```
$(this).next('.fabox').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `for (e in foo)` using `jQuery.each()`, is a lot cleaner and here your e is a global variable which is pretty bad, with each that mistake can't happen.

Also use `$(function(){});` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){});` it does exactly the same but you get better footprint and your code is a bit easier to read.

And in the dom ready function you don't need $ as argument, that when you need a closure and is a way to guarantee $ is jQuery inside the closure.

```
(function($) {
  // your code
})(jQuery);
```

So your code end up like this instead of what you have

```
$(function() {

    $('.color-picker').each(function() {
        if (this.id) {
            $('#' + this.id + '_color').farbtastic('#' + this.id);
        };
    }).click(function() {
        $(this).next().fadeIn();
    });

    $('.fabox').hide();

    $(document).mousedown(function() {
        $('.fabox:visible').fadeOut();
    });
});​
```

And I think your problem might be idtencial IDs so it confuse the plugin, but to be fair it would easier if you post the HTML output rather than the PHP code as it's the DOM we want to see and it's hard to guess without knowing what the PHP variables are outputting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply gillesc. The code you provided not only didn't work as I wanted to, but also now farbtastic is not working at all. I edited the post to provide the HTML OUTPUT.

Comment: Sorry didn't had the mean to test it. Ah your problem is here then when you do $('.fabox').hide(); you ar hidding and and when you do fadeIn() you do the same because it's a class all element containing that class are affected, thus they all show up. So you need to transverse the DOM relative to the element click. I'll update my post

Comment: As your color picker is next to your .fadbox `$(this).next().fadeIn();` inside the click handler should do the trick

Comment: Same thing as ericissocial told me and yes this did the trick! Many thanks to both of you guys!!!

Comment: You can also use the :visible pseudo selector to grab the visible one and hide it `$('.fabox:visible').fadeOut(); ` http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: glad your sorted, as extra note `$(this).parent().find('.fabox').fadeIn();` will be slower than `$(this).next().fadeIn();` as you transverse up, use more function calls and use the CSS engine, when next() wont.